# Navision 2009 permissions error in codeunit, searching for more information

Tags: navision

I get this strange error in Navision 2009 R2, when using codeunits.
Im accessing this codeunit by Web-service with Customer license.

Do you know a way to get more information about the error?

I looked in Event Viewer without success.

See picture below
[Error from Navision web service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgAAl.png)

Comment: Can you post your codeunit?

Comment: I'd say this is "handmade" error. So you should look inside codeunit to see in which case it's thrown. The only thing that is confusing me is ArgumentException type of error. Maybe you passing some incorrect arguments.

Comment: I will check about the "handmade" from other places.
I can't post the codeunit